# Varnish 3 ignore the req.backend directive

Tags: varnish, regex, web, cache

Varnish3 is ignoring the req.backend directive.

As explained on the documentation ([here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/advanced_backend_servers.html)), I've set two backends, and the regex for redirecting the request to the correct one. By the way, seems liks Varnish is just ignoring 
the directive, obviously I'm missing something :-)

I want to catch awesomedomain.it as well as awesomedomain.it/whatever, while all the others domain just should point to default backend.

Any help is appreciated.

```
backend local {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8000";
}

backend default {
    .host = "10.8.0.2";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {

if (req.http.host ~ "/awesomedomain\.it/") {
    set req.backend = local;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first backend is the default backend. The name of the backend doesn't matter

Comment: Weird, all my domains are redirected to the "default" backend, even if its not the first.